# VHDL code for converting floating point to fixed point?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl

I want to solve equation that have integer & floating point variables so I want to convert from floating point to fixed point .
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by your scale factor, convert to integer, rescale. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using VHDL 2008's fixed_pkg and float_pkg, or the mostly backwards-compatible equivalents from http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/, look at the to_ufixed, to_sfixed, and to_float functions which provide these conversions.

For example:

```
signal my_fixed : sfixed(15 downto -7);
signal my_float : float(5 downto -13);
...
my_fixed <= to_sfixed(my_float, 15, -7);
```